# ReadFile only returns after newline

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, io

I'm trying to read every character pressed in my console in realtime.
I'm using ReadFile to read from stdin, but it seems to only complete the read operation after a newline (when I press enter).
Here is my code:

```
    char buf[1] = { 0 };
    HANDLE stdInHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), stdOutHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    while (true) {
        ReadFile(stdInHandle, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL, NULL);
        WriteFile(stdOutHandle, buf, sizeof(buf), NULL, NULL);
    }
```

How would I read the characters pressed realtime, instead of after a newline?

Comment: Terminals, even the Windows command window, are usually *line buffered*. The terminal doesn't "send" the input until the user has pressed the `Enter` key.

Comment: `ReadConsole` or `ReadConsoleInput`

Comment: Also note that Microsoft recommend you use [`ReadConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) to read text from consoles.

Comment: Lastly about how to solve your problem: You need to [set the console mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) to not be line-buffered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've mentioned in a comment you could use [`SetConsoleMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) to disable line-buffering:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    HANDLE hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE hOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Get the current console mode
    DWORD mode;
    GetConsoleMode(hInput, &mode);

    // Save the current mode, so we can restore it later
    DWORD original_mode = mode;

    // Disable the line input mode
    mode &= ~ENABLE_LINE_INPUT;

    // And set the new mode
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, mode);

    // Then read and write input...
    for (;;)
    {
        TCHAR buffer[1];
        DWORD nread = 0;

        // TODO: Need to add some error checking here!
        ReadConsole(hInput, buffer, 1, &nread, nullptr);
        WriteConsole(hOutput, buffer, nread, nullptr, nullptr);

        // Allow some way to exit the program
        if (buffer[0] == 'q' || buffer[0] == 'Q')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Restore the original console mode
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, original_mode);
}
```

Comment: Don’t forget to _restore_ the console mode before terminating, or your users may dislike you.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Good idea! :)

Comment: It works if I run it in windows cmd. It doesn't work if I run it in Cygwin.

Comment: @LovelyHanibal Cygwin is a Unix-like emulation layer, including its terminal. The solution in my answer should work for all terminal windows that uses the Windows console, which I don't know if Cygwin does. For Cygwin, or other Unix-like systems, I recommend you do some reading about **ncurses** instead.